# Rspec Capybara cannot login into my rails-react app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm using Rails `6` with react webpack. I've user authentication setup by rails and UI setup by React in `app/javascript/components/Auth/Login.js`.

Now, I've to test the login feature with RSpec, Capybara and Selenium. Here is my scenario:

```
scenario "user authentication with email on login page", js: true do
  ui_user = create(:confirmed_user)

  visit '/login'

  fill_in "Email", with: ui_user.email
  fill_in "password", with: "12345678"

  click_button 'Login'

  # Wait for 10 sec as React/Redux AJAX request is completed
  sleep 10

  # After successful login, redirect to /dashboard
  expect(page).to have_selector("h1", text: "Hello from Dashboard")
  expect(page).to have_selector("p", text: "Email: #{ui_user.email}")
end
```

I'm testing on Ubuntu 18.04 Server(GUI Less) and I've setup `firefox` and `xvfb`.

Login behavior: When user clicks `Login` button, react/redux will make a API call and add a Localstorage item, then redirects to `/dashboard`

The problem is when testing in above scenario, when the `Login` button is clicked by capybara, nothing happens. I.e., My react/redux app is making an API call(I can see test logs), but it somehow fails to redirect. I don't even know if it's saving the localstorage. I took a screenshot(`capybara-screenshot`) and confirm that `fill_in` data is correct and `Login` button is also clicked.

Here is my `rails_helper`

```
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

Comment: is it working on non-headless mode in your local and not working on Ubuntu server?

Comment: I code on my ubuntu server which has VS Code server installed. So the app works properly in `development`, but when I test using Rspec it fails.